# Excel Sum Total all Values of all Seconds within Minute together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a Data In Excel as Under:

> ```
> Time  StockName   Rate    Diff    Qty
> 09:15:01  ACC 1519    4.8 454
> 09:15:01  ACC 1517.95 -1.05   454
> 09:15:02  ACC 1520    1   58
> 09:15:02  ACC 1519.65 -0.35   57
> 09:15:07  BEL 1519.25 -0.4    69
> 09:15:09  ACC 1521.85 2.6 108
> 09:15:09  ACC 1521.55 -0.3    107
> 09:15:13  BEL 1522.35 0.8 225
> 09:15:17  ACC 1522.35 0   505
> 09:15:45  ACC 1524.3  0.9 562
> 09:15:50  ABB 1525.2  0.9 53
> 09:15:50  ABB 1525.15 -0.05   53
> 09:15:53  ACC 1525.55 0.4 11
> 09:15:54  ACC 1525.65 0.1 111
> 09:15:58  ACC 1526.25 0.6 65
> 09:16:02  ACC 1528.45 2.2 480
> 09:16:02  ACC 1527.65 -0.8    479
> 09:16:06  ACC 1528.75 1.1 74
> 09:16:37  ACC 1526.8  0.75    235
> 09:16:41  ACC 1526.4  -0.4    209
> 09:16:46  ACC 1527.5  1.1 160
> 09:16:50  ACC 1526.8  -0.7    10
> 09:16:56  ACC 1527.3  0.5 91
> 09:17:00  ACC 1527.35 0.05    175
> 09:17:05  ACC 1527    -0.35   588
> 09:17:09  ACC 1527.4  0.4 500
> 09:17:13  ACC 1527.7  0.3 401
> 09:17:49  ACC 1525.7  0.7 147
> 09:17:57  ACC 1525.7  0   507
> 09:18:04  ACC 1523.55 -2.15   776
> 09:18:50  BEL 1522    -0.1    125
> 09:18:54  BEL 1522    0   1162
> 09:18:59  ACC 1523.5  1.5 315
> 09:19:05  ACC 1521.5  -2  700
> 09:19:12  ACC 1521.1  -0.4    137
> 09:19:18  ACC 1521.65 0.55    5
> 09:19:22  ACC 1521.1  -0.55   357
> 09:19:26  ACC 1521.05 -0.05   1
> 09:19:30  ACC 1520.15 -0.9    816
> 09:19:36  ACC 1520.05 -0.1    56
> 09:19:43  ACC 1521.15 1.1 10
> 09:19:48  ACC 1524    2.85    5144
> 09:19:52  ACC 1523    -1  153
> 09:20:00  ACC 1522.75 -0.25   31
> 09:20:07  ACC 1522.5  -0.25   40
> ```

I want to Add all Quantities ("Qty") withiin Each Minute for Each StockName quoted Seconds.

I tried `SumIFS` Function when I put in Conditions Stating Column to Sum, StockName to Sum (Eg ACC), and use Operators Time Column > (Greater than) & > (Less than) a Particular time say >=09.19.01 and Less than <09:21:00 to get Sum of all Quantities Traded for ACC within the 1Minute of 9.20am. However this was to be done for all Scripts with diff time frames and thus too Much Calculations, making the sheet very slow.

Thus I tried to Convert Time Format in hh:mm and then tried to Calculate stating that time = 09:20 . However this does not work as excel still considers seconds and does not total up accurately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the format will not change the value. Try rounding down with a formula like this:

```
=FLOOR(A2,1/60/24)
```

Then change the rounded cells from formula's to values (*copy, paste Values*), so they will not recalculate. Now use the SUMIF(S) function, with the new rounded column as *range*.

PS: you should consider using a pivottable in stead of SUMIF(S).